# Ошибка с MediaView/Media/MediaPlayer в JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, mediaplayer

Ошибка с MediaView/Media/MediaPlayer, при запуске кода:

```
Pane pane=new Pane();
Media media = new Media(file);
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
mediaView.setMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer);
mediaPlayer.play();
pane.getChildren().add(mediaView);
pane.setPrefSize(media.getWidth(), media.getHeight());
System.out.println(media.getDuration().toSecond());
System.out.println(media.getWidth());
System.out.println(media.getHeight());
```

В консоль выводится:

> 0
>
> 0
>
> 0

Это приводит к некорректному отображению медиа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, сразу после создания плеер находится в состоянии `UNKNOWN`. Перед тем, как проверять размеры, 
нужно дождаться, когда плеер перейдет в состояние `READY`:

```
    mediaPlayer.setOnReady(() -> {
        System.out.println(media.getDuration().toSeconds());
        System.out.println(media.getWidth());
        System.out.println(media.getHeight());
    });
```

Во-вторых, если произойдет ошибка, то плеер не перейдет в состояние `READY` и останется в состоянии `UNKNOWN`. Чтобы отследить это, добавьте код обработки ошибки, например:

```java
    mediaPlayer.setOnError(() -> {
        System.out.println(mediaPlayer.getError());
    });
```

Это поможет вам определить проблему и двигаться дальше.

К примеру, для файла [big_buck_bunny.mp4](https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement-files/blob/master/big_buck_bunny.mp4) в Java 8u92 под Windows XP я получил:

> MediaException: MEDIA_UNSUPPORTED : [com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.gstreamer.GSTMediaPlayer@115a68d] ERROR_MEDIA_AAC_FORMAT_UNSUPPORTED: ERROR_MEDIA_AAC_FORMAT_UNSUPPORTED

Следовательно мне либо нужен файл в другом формате, либо нужно установить кодеки, указанные в системных требованиях в разделах "JavaFX Media" на страницах:
[JavaFX 2 Certified System Configurations](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/supportedconfigurations-1506746.html)
[JavaFX 2.2.5 System Requirements](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/system_requirements_2-2-5/jfxpub-system_requirements_2-2-5.htm)

Answer (score -1):

```
pane.getChildren().add(pane);
```

Добавление дочерним объектом самого себя едва ли хорошая идея.